# getting 503 while scraping a website which is using cloudflare

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, cloudflare

I'm using scrapy for scraping websites,but this website is using cloudflare. So i'm not getting proper response.I'm getting 503 for response Does anyone have any idea or solution about it?
domain-www.aptekaolmed.pl

Comment: This is not the the sort of question that can easily be answered. None of us control that site, and scraping is not programming as such.

Comment: may be [this](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-cloudflare-middleware) will help

Comment: status code 503 means service unavailable.

Comment: But this website works on after filling capatcha abut in scrapy framework and request module I did not get the response.